# Chain Link VRF not working Wrong argument count for function call: 3 arguments given but expected 2. return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, seed)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, chainlink

**Summary**

The documentation for getting random numbers in chain-link doesn't work.

**Description**

Generating random numbers doesn't work when following the chain-link documentation.  I got an error after copy and pasting the code from the documentation into remix.  The contract does not compile due to the following error.

> gist-55c1263fcfc710f834aa38b7bbd21dc1/VRFD20.sol:60:21: TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 3 arguments given but expected 2.
> requestId = requestRandomness(s_keyHash, s_fee, userProvidedSeed);

I get this error whenever I include the following line in my code.

`requestRandomness(s_keyHash, s_fee, userProvidedSeed);`

This error prevents me from generating random numbers using chain-link.

**Steps To Reproduce:**

1. Head over to the documentation here : https://docs.chain.link/docs/intermediates-tutorial/
2. Scroll down and click on deploy contract using remix (blue outline button)
3. Click on one of the folders that looks like 536123b61468ad4442cfc4278e8de577 then RandomNumberConsumer.sol
4. Navigation to the Solidity Compiler Tab and click on Compile RandomNumber.sol.

**Additional Information**

This error happens for me whenever I call the following line of code.
`requestRandomness(s_keyHash, s_fee, userProvidedSeed);`

Comment: This looks like an issue. I've flagged to the team. Could you please additionally make an issue on the chainlink repo? https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink

Comment: Remove the userProvidedSeed and it will update. The documentation hasn't been updated yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/documentation/pull/167) in flight to update the documentation. The new API will looks like:

```js
requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
```

instead of:

```js
requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, userprovidedseed);
```

Comment: That worked for me.  Thank you so much for your help!  I just checked out their documentation and the requestRandomness() function has been updated.